# Telerik Filter Control not working on IIS6 SErver

Tags: asp.net, telerik-grid

I have create one rad grid with telerik, that's working fine in my one server on IIS 7 but that's not working in IIS6 server.

I already isntalled telerik web.ui installer on my server.